# I am trying to upload image through modal in laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

Below is my controller file **ServiceProviderController.php**  - controller

What am I doing wrong in this case?

I am getting below error:

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException", file: 
  "C:\xampp\htdocs\laundry_admin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumi
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class ServiceProviderController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request )
    {
        $sp = new ServiceProvider;
        $sp->shop_name = $request->input('spname');
        $sp->mobile_number = $request->input('spmobile');
        $sp->shop_address = $request->input('spaddress');
        // $sp->shop_image = $request->input('splogo');
        $sp->latitude = $request->input('splatitude');
        $sp->longitude = $request->input('splongitude');
        $sp->rating = $request->input('sprating');
        $sp->delivery_days = $request->input('spdeliverydays');

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            //  Let's do everything here
            if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
                //
                $validated = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'string|max:40',
                    'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:1014',
                ]);
                $extension = $request->image->extension();
                $request->image->storeAs('/public/images', $validated['name'].".".$extension);
                $url = Storage::url($validated['name'].".".$extension);
                $sp->shop_image = $url;
                $file = File::create([
                   'name' => $validated['name'],
                    'url' => $url,
                ]);
                Session::flash('success', "Success!");
                return \Redirect::back();
            }
        }
        abort(500, 'Could not upload image :(');

        $sp->save();
        // return redirect('home')->with('success','Customer added successfully');

    }

}
```

Below is my **ServiceProvider.php**    Model class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ServiceProvider extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'service_provider';
    protected $fillable = [
        'shop_name',
        'mobile_number',
        'shop_address',
        'shop_image',
        'latitude',
        'longitude',
        'rating',
        'delivery_days'
    ];
}
```

Below is my blade file **service_provider.blade.php**     - blade file

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="add" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Service Provider</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="" id="addform">
                    
                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="spname" class="">Shop Name</label>    
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="spname" placeholder="Name" type="name" name="spname" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="spmobile" class="">Mobile No.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="spmobile" placeholder="Mobile No." type="number" name="spmobile" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="splatitude" class="">Latitude.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="splatitude" type="number" name="splatitude" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="splongitude" class="">Longitude.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="splongitude" type="number" name="splongitude" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="spaddress" class="">Shop Address</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <textarea id="spaddress" name="spaddress" class="form-control"></textarea>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="image" class="">logo</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="image" type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="sprating" class="">Rating.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="sprating"  type="number" name="sprating" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="spdeliverydays" class="">Delivery Days.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="spdeliverydays" type="number" name="spdeliverydays" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="position-relative form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 my-auto text-center">
                                <label for="exampleaddress" class="">Services</label>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3 text-center">
                                        <label for="exampleaddress" class="mr-2">Dry Clean</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">   
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3 text-center">
                                        <label for="exampleaddress" class="mr-2">Wash & Fold</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">   
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3 text-center">
                                        <label for="exampleaddress" class="mr-2">Wash & Iron</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success"> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-3 text-center">
                                        <label for="exampleaddress" class="mr-2">Stream Press</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success"> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" id="addserviceprovider" class="mt-1 btn-wide btn-pill btn-shadow btn-hover-shine btn btn-primary">Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#addform').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/add_sp",
                data: $('#addform').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    $('#add').modal('hide')
                    alert("Service Provider added Successfully");
                    
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    alert("Service provider not added");
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>




</html>
```

Here is my **web.php**     - route file

```
Route::post('/add_sp','ServiceProviderController@store');
```

Comment: Add `enctype: "multipart/form-data"` on your form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: @CBroe this does not answer my question at all.
i have also refered many links and tried a lot but it is unable to work it looks like something wrong in my controller file

Comment: Yes, it does. You can not perform a file upload using jQuery’s `serialize`, you need to use `FormData` / File API.

Answer (score -1):

Please update you ajax code with below which i share because you have post file data. You need to add

> enctype: 'multipart/form-data'

because when you post data with file these things must be added.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add_sp",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: $('#addform').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        $('#add').modal('hide')
        alert("Service Provider added Successfully");
        
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
        alert("Service provider not added");
    }
});
```

Comment: You can not perform a file upload using `serialize`.